# OpenCV set a channel to a value C++

Tags: c++, opencv

What is the best way to set a channel of a mat to a value while letting the other channels to their current value?

For example, if I have a 4 channel Mat and for some reason I need to set one of the channels to a value, but with the others retaining their current values, what operations are the best?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

As pseudo code you can write a function that takes input an image this way:

1. Split image into channels
2. Modify channel of interest
3. Merge them again

for example

```
Mat img(5,5,CV_64FC3); // declare three channels image 
Mat ch1, ch2, ch3; // declare three matrices 
// "channels" is a vector of 3 Mat arrays:
vector<Mat> channels(3);
// split img:
split(img, channels);
// get the channels (follow BGR order in OpenCV)
ch1 = channels[0];
ch2 = channels[1];
ch3 = channels[2]; 
// modify channel// then merge

merge(channels, img);
```

Comment: good sample thx!

Comment: If it was for a single channel you could use `cv::extractChannel` and `cv::insertChannel`